# Minimize all windows on active workspace only

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any possibility to minimize all windows on active workspace only. Super + d minimizes all windows on all workspaces, but I need only on the active one.
Linux Mint, Xfce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in possibility for that. But I found a [bash script](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9436) on Xfce forum, that does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: +1. I was thinking of `wmctrl` and check the link in your link, and yes, it is using that program.